# How to plot the graph of this given set in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

Can anyone help me plot the graph of the set $$B=\{(a_1+a_2, a_1a_2):a_1,a_2\in\mathbb{R},|a_1|<1,|a_2|<1\}.$$

Ok so I can shade the region $|x|<2$ and $|y|<1$. But do not know how to proceed after that. And above sets is real roots of the equation $x^2-\alpha x+\beta$ whose modulus is less than 1.
Will it be the intersection of the shaded area above and the parabola $x^2-4y>0$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> Your set can be interpreted as the image of the open square $(-1, 1) \times (-1, 1)$ under the polynomial mapping $$(a_1,a_2)\mapsto(a_1+a_2,a_1a_2).$$That doesn't immediately answer, but should give a workable strategy for proceeding. (It might help to say more about what you know mathematically, e.g., precalculus? Single- or multi-variable calculus?)

Comment: I have studied multivariable calculus.

Comment: Ah, good: In that case, first find the image of the boundary. If that encloses a bounded region it should be straightforward to show that region is the image. If not, find the critical points of the mapping (where the differential has rank $0$ or $1$), and look at the image of the critical set as well.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang The derivative is $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\a_2 & a_2 \end{bmatrix}$$ so the critical points occur when $a_1 = a_2$. How does this help us understand the region? P.S. I posted an answer to this question, I'd be very curious if you had any comments about it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have time now to write a very formal answer, but hopefully this should help:

Let's examine what happens at the extreme cases, when one of $a_1, a_2$ is $\pm 1$.

$$\begin{align*}
a_1 &= +1: &\{(a_2 + 1, a_2): |a_2| \le 1 \}\\
a_1 &= -1: &\{(a_2 - 1, -a_2): |a_2| \le 1 \}\\
a_2 &= +1: &\{(a_1 + 1, a_1): |a_1| \le 1 \}\\
a_2 &= -1: &\{(a_1 - 1, -a_1): |a_1| \le 1 \}\\
\end{align*}$$
These four sets form the red part:

[image]

Now instead of fixing $a_2$ as $\pm 1$, fix it as some $b$ with $|b| < 1$ and let $a_1$ range over $[-1, 1]$. This gives the blue line. As $b$ changes, the ends of the blue line remain on the red part. I encourage you to play with the $b$ slider on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zh8pr9zqmb).

So it seems like the region will be bounded by the red part below, and by some sort of blue parabola-like curve above.

To find the blue parabola above, let's fix the $x$ coordinate as $c$ (with $|c| < 2$) and find the corresponding point in the region with the largest $y$ coordinate. This is the optimization problem

$$\begin{align*}\max a_1a_2\\
\text{s.t. } \ a_1 + a_2 = c\\
-1 \le a_1 \le 1\\
-1 \le a_2 \le 1
\end{align*}$$

We solve this problem by eliminating $a_1$. We have $a_1 = c - a_2$, and the requirement $-1 \le a_1 \le 1$ turns into $c - 1 \le a_2 \le c+1.$ So the optimization problem turns into

$$\begin{align*}\max (c - a_2)a_2\\
\text{s.t. } -1 \le a_2 \le 1\\
c - 1 \le a_2 \le c+1
\end{align*}$$

Assume $c \ge 0$. The case for $c < 0$ is similar. The problem turns into
$$\begin{align*}\max (c - a_2)a_2\\
\text{s.t. } c-1 \le a_2 \le 1\\
\end{align*}$$
which is simply a quadratic over the interval $[c-1, 1]$. For $0 \le c \le 2$, the maximum occurs at $a_2 = \frac c2$ and it is $\frac {c^2}{4}.$ Therefore the upper boundary for the region should be $f(c) = c^2/4$. So the region should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, the set in question is the image of the open unit square $S_{0} := (-1, -1) \times (-1, 1)$ under the polynomial mapping
$$
f(a_{1}, a_{2}) = (a_{1} + a_{2}, a_{1}a_{2}).
$$
The open square is contained in the square $S := [-1, 1] \times [-1, 1]$, which is compact, and therefore has compact image under the continuous mapping $f$.

**Lemma**: If $y = f(x)$ is a point of the boundary of the image $f(S)$, then $x$ is either a critical point of $f$ or lies on the boundary of $S$.

*Proof*: Contrapositively, if $x$ is an interior point of $S$ and is not a critical point of $f$, the inverse function theorem guarantees some disk about $x$ maps diffeomorphically to a neighborhood of $f(x)$. Particularly, $f(x)$ is an interior point of the image. (Note the similarity with the situation for local extrema of functions of one variable.)

---

The critical points of $f$ are the line $a_{1} = a_{2}$ (easily checked), the images of the boundary of $S$ and the critical set are easily found (see also Ovi's answer), and these curves border a unique bounded plane region. Finally, in this example, we have
$$
f(S_{0}) = f(S \setminus \partial S) = f(S) \setminus f(\partial S).
$$
To prove this, it may help to note that $f(a_{2}, a_{1}) = f(a_{1}, a_{2})$ for all $(a_{1}, a_{2})$ in $S$, so the image of $S$ is the image of the triangle $T \subset S$ where $-1 \leq a_{2} \leq a_{1} \leq 1$; and to show $f$ is bijective on $T$.

Comment: There's more to be said about the geometry of $f$, but it's fun to discover these things on one's own; trying here to stay in the realm of generalities in the spirit of "teaching to fish."

Comment: Cool answer, I learned something new: boundary points of $f(S)$ come from critical points of $f(S)$ too. What other questions might we want to answer about the geometry of $f$?

Comment: @Ovi: I wasn't thinking so much of other questions, but pleasant geometric properties, such as the way the blue segments vary in your (+1) answer, and their envelope, which is a parabola as you note. Drawing several blue segments gives a ruler-and-pencil method for approximating the quadratic spline with specified control points.

Comment: I see, thanks. By the way I fixed the Desmos link in my answer if you want to use it. It's pretty fun to play around with those sliders.